# facebook JSON decode with php?

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

So im finally able to pull data from the graph API on facebook and the is the JSON array that I am getting.  I was wondering if you could provide any advice for writing this to a database using php.  The field names need to go into the database clean and not serialized.  I have an ajax calendar that will be pulling birthday information.

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [uid] => 111222333
                [name] => Noah J 
                [birthday_date] => 11/21/1982
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [uid] => 111222333
                [name] => Ana B 
                [birthday_date] => 04/07/1981
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [uid] => 111222333
                [name] => Ric C
                [birthday_date] => 10/01/1982
            )
```

Thanks in advanced!!!

Answer (score 3):

You should use the PHP function `json_decode()` ([docu link](http://pt2.php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php)). It's the best option. It will turn your JSON array into a PHP array easy to work with.

Comment: I was looking at this but was unsure if it encoded it. Thanks!  I will let you know when I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $a = json_decode($a); ?>
```